# Controlling a flow of a program

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have start() and want to continue with my code only after  getCityInformation() is fully completed. Console should print ('getCityInformation' => 'done' => 'finished'). How do I control this flow?

```
async start() {
    await this.getCityInformation().then(() => console.log('done'));
    console.log('finished');
}

async getCityInformation() {
    this.apiService.getProductsByCategory(this.city.CategoryID)
        .subscribe((data: Product[]) => {
            console.log('getCityInformation')
            this.products = data;
        },
            (err) => console.log(err),
            () => this.loadActivities()
        );
}
```

Comment: what is it printing now?

Comment: it prints ('done' => 'finished' => 'getCityInformation')

Comment: It's because getProductsByCategory() is also async. I'd expect you could maybe await that as well. Or if that method returns a Promise, then return that Promise as the return of the getCityInformation method (i.e. `return this.apiService.getProductsByCategory(`...etc

Comment: @viiskis does it help if you add the `return` keyword before `this.apiService.getProductsByCategory`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current order of `done`, `finished` and `getCityInformation` makes sense, because in the async `getCityInformation()` you actually return immediately (don't for example `await` for something). So the chain goes:

1. `start()` calls `getCityInformation()`
2. `getCityInformation()` subscribes to an observable and returns
3. `getCityInformation()` is now done and `start()` prints `done`
4. `start()` prints `finished`
5. the callback in `getCityInformation()` gets an update and prints `getCityInformation`

To fix this, you need to wait in `getCityInformation()` until you are ready with the observable. For example, you could return a `Promise` that is fulfilled when you have all the data you need.

Answer (score 1):

> you need to return promise to wait for the result of
>   `getCityInformation` function

```
async start() {
    await this.getCityInformation().then(() => console.log('done'));
    console.log('finished');
}

async getCityInformation() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.apiService.getProductsByCategory(this.city.CategoryID)
        .subscribe((data: Product[]) => {
            console.log('getCityInformation')
            this.products = data;
            resolve(data) 
        },
            (err) => reject(err) ,
            () => this.loadActivities()
        );

    })    
}
```

Comment: you should really explain your answer, instead of just dumping code. It may not be obvious to everyone what exactly you've changed, or, more importantly, _why_. If it was so obvious, the OP would probably not have the issue in the first place.

Comment: @ADyson, I think the code is self-explained but I will write here text also

Comment: that's half of it. You've done the "what" but not the "why". It's only self-explanatory if understand quite well about async code. Clearly OP is struggling a bit with that. So you should explain the concept behind your suggestion as well.